# Laravel Voyager not showing images

Tags: laravel, voyager

I have created a Laravel app using installatron on godaddy.com (shared hosting). After installing Voyager the default admin avatar is not showing. The storage link is automatically created by Voyager. But when I open the admin panel voyager tries to get admin avatar from *[app_url]/storage/users/default.png* and receives a 404. The avatar is at *[app_url]/public/storage/users/default.png*

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51noG.png)

**Versions:**
Laravel: **5.8**
Voyager: **1.3**

Comment: You haven't set up your document root properly. `public` should never be a part of the URL. [Read the instructions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#configuration) on how to properly set up Laravel on a remote host, and point your document root to `public` so that your paths are resolved properly, and you can avoid directory traversal attacks.

Answer (score 7):

Put port number in .env file if use localhost

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:port_number
```

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the exact same issue before, after checking the APP_URL, go ahead and execute

```
php artisan config:clear
```

After that try again.

If it doesn't work, delete the symlink storage in public/ and execute

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check if the APP_URL in your .env file is correct.

That it equals the domain-name you bought at godaddy and also the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS).

Comment: Or weather using a port. Ex: http://localhost:8000/

Answer (score 2):

in my case 3 steps:

1- correct App_URL in .env file (do`nt forget port number )
example:

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

2- delete storage file from [project path]\public

3- run: `php artisan storage:link`

enjoy:)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the setting in `filesystems.php`.

```
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/nameOfMyRootFolder/storage/app/public',
```

Then it was able to resolve the image link correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the 'APP_URL' variable into the .env file to your localhost route.

For example:

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

I was facing this issue today

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem in local try with adding port to `APP_URL`.
**But** in the server problem was the *"Storage"* folder which is in *public* directory.

**UPDATE Feb 2022**
please notice the symbolic link must be existed in your root

Answer (score 1):

In your .env file, replace the app URL.

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:port
```

Answer (score 1):

if you were using sail, try run :

```
 sail artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the setting in filesystems.php,
disks -> public -> "url => env('APP_URL').'/public/storage'"

Answer (score 0):

Please check APP_URL=<> in your .env file it should be basically like

```
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Check APP_URL in .env file, make sure that APP_URL in .env file is to the public folder of your project

APP_URL=http://localhost/your-project-name/public/

Answer (score 0):

APP_URL setting worked for me. I'm running the app in a container so I have to put the port used from my host not 8000. I have port 8000 mapped to 8186, so I have to put APP_URL=http://localhost:8186

Answer (score 0):

work for me:

image see in url `http://localhost:8000/storage/users/default.png` but dont in /admin panel `(http://localhost/storage/users/default.png 404)` its a port problem with storage

change in config/app to

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost:8000')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still wonder why, check this answer in [voyager issues](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/5362#issuecomment-860007292)

*Since FILESYSTEM_DRIVER was not defined by default in Laravel the public storage was used, but in Laravel 8.5.19 the default value was added.*

Answer (score 0):

**After changed at filesystem.php**

```
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('../storage/app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

It's Working perfectly